# stack area chart visualization tableau

Tags: analytics, data-visualization, tableau-api, stacked-area-chart

Anyone can explain what happen with this chart, please. For instance, Eastern Asia have 0.3xx Tone, but why the line is go down until  y=0k. Why they didn't just stay in the end of the sum of Region before.

[image]

Comment: Good point. You might want to contact Tableau support. Tableau does something similar for negative values, which is understandable, but they could just hide the marks for zeros. In the meantime, you could hide or filter out marks where SUM(Tone) = 0 as a workaround